# Service 'Windows Licensing Monitoring Service (WLMS)' cannot be started

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-services

Since I'm looking to improve my Sharepoint knowledge, I downloaded the 2010 Information Worker Demonstration and Evaluation Virtual Machine (SP1) from Microsoft

https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

Everything was running fine until I decided to install my first Windows updates (120+ updates). After I restarted the machine, some of the programs don't work, and I get the following error, when the **Start Services** script runs:

```
Start-Service : Service 'Windows Licensing Monitoring Service (WLMS)' cannot be
 started due to the following error: Cannot open WLMS service on computer '.'.
At C:\scripts\startServices.ps1:1 char:82
+ gwmi win32_service -filter "StartMode='Auto' and State='Stopped'" | start-ser
vice <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControl
   ler:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman
   ds.StartServiceCommand
```

Any ideas? Googling isn't helping.

Comment: Has the eval expired by any chance?

Comment: @DaveM: No. Windows License valid for 131 days. I get that message in my desktop.

Comment: @DaveM: One thing I don't know if it is relevant. The Office 2010 eval license in the machine expired and I installed a valid license I had. At the time, no errors were shown, but this is the first time I restart the machine since that modification.